# Calculus of Variation - Question with Integral constraint

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm stuck on this question,

Let $V$ be an open ball in $\mathbb R^3$ in $ { x,y,z \text{ st }x^2 +y^2 +z^2<1}$

I need to minimise the integral $$ \iiint_V (u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2) \, dx \, dy \, dz $$

when subject to constraints
$$ \iiint_V u \, dx \, dy \, dz = 4 \pi $$ 
and $$ u=1 \text{ on } \partial V$$

I've got down to this

$$ F= u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2 \text{ and } G=u$$
The Euler-Lagrange $$ {\partial\over \partial x}\left( {\partial (F- \lambda G)\over \partial u_x } \right)
 + {\partial\over \partial y}\left( {\partial (F- \lambda G)\over \partial u_y } \right)+{\partial\over \partial z}\left( {\partial (F- \lambda G)\over \partial u_z } \right)- {\partial\over \partial u}( F- \lambda G) =0 $$

I have worked out the above to be as follows and I know you simplify it to

$$ 2 u_{xx} + 2u_{yy}+ 2u_{zz} - \lambda =0$$
$$  \nabla^2 (u)= {\lambda \over 2} $$

Any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: What if you solve $2\Delta u=\lambda$ and satisfy the boundary condition $u=1$ on $\partial V$?